# Issue in asp.net web application Azure App service remote debugging

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm trying to debug my web application which is hosted in app service. While am attaching process to local code am getting below issue.Can one help on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few options that you can try out and see if that helps.

- Ensure Visual Studio is opened in Administrator Mode and follow the
  same steps.
- Instead of attaching the debugger via Server Explorer, go to Debug >
  Attach to Process...
- Open the Outbound ports 4022 for VS on firewall.
- You can also go through the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure?view=vs-2017#remote_debug_azure_app_service

I hope it helps.